# Result of sequelize findByPk

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to find an itme with the `id` is: **1**
`const student = await this.db.Student.findByPk(1)`

when I get the result then console it(`console.log(student)`)

```
student {
  dataValues: { id: 1, name: 'Darush', family: 'Hamidi' },
  _previousDataValues: { id: 1, name: 'Darush', family: 'Hamidi' },
  _changed: Set(0) {},
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    raw: true,
    attributes: [ 'id', 'name', 'family' ]
  },
  isNewRecord: false
}
```

then send the student to browser result will be (`res.send(student)`)?

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Darush",
  "family": "Hamidi"
}
```

why we have a difference ?

Answer (score 5):

I set `rwa` to `true`: It works Perfectly

```
const student = await this.db.Student.findByPk(1,{ raw: true })
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference appears because using `findByPk` method (and all similar ones) you get a Sequelize model's instance and not a plain object and when you pass this model instance to `res.send` it is serialized into plain object with model attributes only.
If you wish to get a plain object from a model instance call `get({ plain: true })` and then there will be no difference.

```
const plainStudentObj = student.get({ plain: true })
res.send(plainStudentObj)
```